# Python - Parsing JSON Data through user defined function

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a [JSON Text File](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v2.0.json)

Inside the JSON text file, there are columns like id, title, context, question, is_impossible, answer_start and text.

I am trying to read this into a Pandas DataFrame. I am new to Python and JSON. So giving a go with a function definition.

Here is my code,

```
def squad_json_pd_df(json_dict):
    mylistsize = len((list(json_normalize(json_dict,'data')['title'])))
    row = []
    for i in range(0,mylistsize):
        data = [c for c in json_dict['data']][i]
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        data_paragraphs = data['paragraphs']
        mytitle = data['title']
        for article_dict in data_paragraphs:
            for answers_dict in article_dict['qas']:
                for answer in answers_dict['answers']:
                    row.append((
                                answers_dict['id'],
                                mytitle,
                                article_dict['context'], 
                                answers_dict['question'], 
                                answers_dict['is_impossible'],
                                answer['answer_start'],
                                answer['text']
                               ))
            df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(row, columns=['id', 'title','context', 'question','is_impossible', 'answer_start', 'answer'])], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
            df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    return df

with open(dev_datapath) as file:
    dev_dict = json.load(file)
    dev_df = squad_json_pd_df(dev_dict)
```

So the problem here is - The is_Impossible column has both true and false values inside it (When I see it in the text file). But after I load in the Pandas dataframe, I can see only false records.

My understanding of the problem is that - The JSON File structure could be different for true records and I am not parsing it correctly in Python.

The Is_Impossible false structure looks as below,

[image: IS_Impossible False Structure]

The Is_Impossible true structure looks as below,

[image: Is_Impossible True Structure]

Comment: Can you provide an example for the json_line? I think a lot of you for loops could be replaced with simpler stuff like data.get('paragraphs', {}).get('qas',{}).get('answers', {}).get('id) for example for the first row - sorry I can see the file...

Comment: @AnnaSemjén Added it to the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't get the "True"-s back is because they are under a different json-tag - they are under "**plausible_answers**" instead of **answers** I think. In your code the answers_dict is only pulled from the "answers" tag from the json - so you never actually loop over the plausible_answers list where the tag would be set to True